# OData controller function to get entity collections using $expand async

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, odata

I recently updated a test OData project from .Net core 3.11 and OData4 to .Net6 core, EF6  and OData8. As part of this I reviewed the Controller code (it was several years old) and implemented async functions.

I noticed that with the older function using `IActionResult<Iqueryable>>` will return related entities when queried using the $expand query option. However when I used `Task<IActionResult>` the related entities return empty.

```
CompaniesController.cs - previous function

[EnableQuery]
[HttpGet("odata/Companies({key})")]
 public ActionResult<IQueryable<Company>> GetbyId([FromODataUri] int key)
 {
     IQueryable<Company> result = _reviewsDbContext.Companies
        .Where(p => p.CompanyId == key)
        .Include("Rating");

         if (result == null)
         {
             return NotFound();
         }
         else
         {
             return Ok(result);
         }

 }
```

and the async update:

```
CompaniesController.cs - updated

[HttpGet("odata/v1/Companies({key})")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IQueryable<Company>>> GetbyId([FromODataUri] int key)
{
    var result = await _reviewsDbContext.Companies
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.CompanyId == key);

         if (result == null)
         {
             return NotFound();
         }
         else
         {
             return Ok(result);
          }
}
```

The other notable difference is .Where versus `FirstOrDefaultAsync`.

I also updated the function to use async `Task<ActionResult<IQueryable>>` using `.FirstOrDefaultAsync` and had the same result (no related entities).

Any suggestions on the best way to introduce an async function while still supporting the $expand query option for related entities?

Thanks.

[Update1] Adding program.cs snippet as per the request in the comments.

```
program.cs
<snippet>

builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddOData(opt => 
        opt.AddRouteComponents("odata",
            new ReviewsEntityDataModel().GetEntityDataModel()
                  
           
  ).Select().Expand().Filter().OrderBy().Count().SetMaxTop(100)
        );
```

Comment: Try calling `.Include("Rating").ToListAsync()`, I had kinda same issue when creating anonymous types of complex object and ToList() was the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the thought. What's interesting is that if I use the Include AND the $expand in the URL then for those collections/entities I get the return. However, as there is a scenario where I need to expand ~3 related entities just adding the include statements creates another issue. You get a warning about split queries - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries

Whereas, the original function I had handles the expand perfectly, but doesn't support async

Comment: Can you show your OData config as well? There was a change in the OData configuration to enable the support of these methods. I think it was post OData 7 you need to call `builder.Select().Expand().Filter().OrderBy().MaxTop(maxxAllowed).Count();`. I'm just guessing that this might be the issue.

Comment: @vendettamit - added as per request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging into this it seems that this is an issue due to Deferred Execution. In short combining [EnableQuery] with async code is not currently supported.

This was called out in a Pluralsight course from Kevin Dockx. I didn't find anything in the docs calling this out, but this would explain the behaviour I'm seeing and [Kevin's example](https://github.com/KevinDockx/BuildingAnODataAPIAspNetCore/blob/main/.NET%205/Finished%20sample/AirVinyl/Controllers/PeopleController.cs)

Basically, use async where it makes sense and where the expansion (or other query options are required, disable async for now.